# Sum a stack of images

Tags: python, image

I have a stack of images and I am looking for a way to

- load the first ten images;
- sum the corresponding arrays;
- plot the result of the sum.

With two images, the code looks like

```
import matplotlib
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from PIL import Image

filename_1 = ('images/image_001.txt')
filename_2 = ('images/image_002.txt')
matrix_1 = np.loadtxt(filename_1)
matrix_2 = np.loadtxt(filename_2)
matrix = (matrix_1 + matrix_2)
plt.imshow(matrix, cmap = cm.Greys_r, interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

How would you extend it to a loop?

Comment: Are you saying just do what you have there but in a loop for all 10 images at once?

Comment: Exactly that's what I'm thinking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

```
import matplotlib
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image_iter = ('images/image_%03d.txt' % i for i in xrange(1, 11))
image_sum = np.loadtxt(next(image_iter))

for image in image_iter:
   image_sum += np.loadtxt(image)

plt.imshow(image_sum, cmap=cm.Greys_r, interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how `matplotlib` handles the matrix so you may need to edit how you format the matrix.

```
import matplotlib
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from PIL import Image

matrix = []

for num in range(20):
    filename = ('images/image_0' + str((num + 1)) + '.txt')
    matrix.append(np.loadtxt(filename))

plt.imshow(matrix, cmap = cm.Greys_r, interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

Just comment below with questions.

Comment: Great that worked! I will edit a few minor mistakes in your answer ;-)